# Insert row into MySQL DB?

Tags: java, sql

The Code:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO `admin` (`id`,`username`,`password`,`access`) VALUES ('"+(numIds+1)+"','"+addedUsername+"','"+addedPassword+"','"+addedAccess+"');";

Statement statementAdd = (Statement) DBconnection.createStatement();
result = statementAdd.executeUpdate(sql);
```

The Error:

```
MySQLLogin.java:133: error: incompatible types
            result = statementAdd.executeUpdate(sql);
                                               ^
required: ResultSet
found:    int
1 error
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please learn using prepared statements. Your code will be cleaner, more robust, and not vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: @user2202426: show us how `result` is declared. `ExecuteUpdate` returns an int, not a ResultSet. 

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html

Answer (score 4):

ExecuteUpdate returns integer it seems you are assigning it to the Result set

Comment: How would I change this then?

Comment: int count = statementAdd.executeUpdate(sql);

Answer (score 0):

For this:

```
'"+(numIds+1)+"'
```

You are either trying to do math with a string or insert a string with into a numeric field.  Given your error message, I suspect the latter.  It's the single quotes that make it a string.

Answer (score 0):

`executeUpdate` returns the number of rows affected (in your case, it will return the number of rows inserted. But you are trying to a assign the returning `int` to a `ResultSet` object.

So just change it to :

```
int insertedRows = statementAdd.executeUpdate(sql);
```

See the [javadocs for `Statement` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29) for more information.